# How to handle key based expiration of collections if there is no parent model in Rails 4.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fragment-caching, ruby-on-rails-4

Since action and page caches and sweepers will be removed from Rails 4.0, I started to use `cache_digests` in my Rails 3.2 application, since I'm suffering from this whole manual expiration nightmare.

But even after reading some tutorials ([How key-based cache expiration works](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3113-how-key-based-cache-expiration-works), [Cache Digests](https://github.com/rails/cache_digests#cache-digests%29), [#387 Cache Digests](http://railscasts.com/episodes/387-cache-digests), ...) I couldn't find a good way to handle views where there is no parent object which could provide a time stamp or something similar.

For example this works flawlessly, if `Document` and `Todolist` use the `touch` option on the `Project` association.

```
# app/views/projects/show.html.erb
<% cache @project do %>
  <%= render @project.documents %>
  <%= render @project.todolists %>
<% end %>
```

But what about the `index` action?

```
# app/views/projects/index.html.erb
<% cache ??? do %>
  <% @projects.each do |project| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Of course I could just use any arbitrary key like `project_index` and expire it on any change of a project model, but that would require a sweeper or an observer and getting rid of them including the explicit expiration is one of the major reasons for key based expiration.

What is the **Rails 4.0** way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this:

```
# app/views/projects/index.html.erb
<% cache @projects do %>
  <% @projects.each do |project| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The projects collection will create the cache key, any changes in the collection in terms of order or objects will create a different key.

It does have some limitations if your views are showing data relating to projects from lower level associations, however this can be dealt with.

Comment: I tried that and it works, of course, but this method results in database access, i.e. every project gets loaded. Compared to that the rendering time is almost neglectable :)

Comment: There will be a saving as all your projects are going to get loaded anyway to run through the rendering loop so at least you are saving on the rendering.  Am not sure but I think the cache command will only load the Updated_at field to generate the keys.  The other thing to bear in mind is that the database will itself be caching so the cost should be mitigated.

Comment: The cache command doesn't only load the `updated_at` field. It calls the `cache_key` method on each of the objects and concatenates the result.

Comment: @MarkStratmann It seems that your blog has gone offline. I can't access the link. Did you move it some where else?

Comment: @Mohamad, sorry that link is now dead, will try to get the page back on line for you however this is now a very old approach.  Having got more experience, caching fragments of the HTML response comes with far too many drawbacks and problems down the line.  In general now I tend to do all the rendering of the UI with Javascript and just use Rails to serve Javascript backends.

Comment: @MarkStratmann thanks! Don't worry about bringing it back. It's not important. I wanted to see how people solved some problems. I have fragments of objects that include a reference to their parent object (e.g.: a `document` partial with `user` info--name, avatar, etc...). When a user updates its avatar, there's no clean way to bust the cache on its `documents`. The user name/avatar/whatever becomes stale. Including the user `updated_at` in the partial cache key might solve this. Perhaps ReactJS or something would work, but I don't have the resources for the extra technical overhead. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
# app/views/projects/index.html.erb
<% cache @projects.scoped.maximum(:updated_at) do %>
  <% @projects.each do |project| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

When a project is updated, a new cache page is created....

Comment: Sadly, even with an index on the `updated_at` field, this results in a query that's about 10 times slower than if you just did `<%= cache @projects %>`, according to my benchmarks: https://gist.github.com/bricker/5518345

Comment: Any idea why? Seems like this should be the most efficient way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't give it too much thought, and I never tried it myself, but you might do the following:

```
class TimestampAsCacheKey
  def initialize(prefix,timestamp)
    @key = prefix + timestamp.to_s
  end
  def cache_key # This is what Rails calls to get a key from object for caching
    @key
  end
end

...
# in your model:
ts = ... # somehow get the most recent timestamp of your projects, like
         # 1) either @projects.to_a.map(&:updated_at).max 
         #    or from `projects` table, like 
         #      Project.order("updated_at DESC").first.updated_at
         #      (you should further optimize the query, of course, but you get the idea)
         #    but probably not, since the whole point is to avoid hitting db
         # 2) or, better yet, from storing it in a global var, special DB table, etc
         #    (just update it there each time you save a project, 
         #    e.g. through after_save / after_commit)
@projects_last_updated_time = TimestampAsCacheKey.new("projects-timestamped-list-",ts)
```

And then in your view:

```
<% cache @projects_last_updated_time do %>
  <% @projects.each do |project| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: + 1 I do this in special cases where the SQL execution is expensive.